# How to clear div content onclick?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a calendar purely from Javascript, but when then previous and next months are shown current content is still present. It should replace the div content. Also, current date should be the only one with red font displayed.

```
<html>
<head><script>

        var now = new Date();
        var year = now.getFullYear();
        var month = now.getMonth();
        var monthName = getMonthName(month);
        var time = now.toLocaleTimeString();
        var date = now.getDate();
        now = null;
        var calElem = document.getElementById("cal");

        function febDays(year) {
            if (year % 4 == 0) {
                return 29;
            } else {
                return 28;
            }
        }

        function getDays(month, year) {
            var days = new Array(12);
            days[0] = 31;
            days[1] = febDays(year);
            days[2] = 31;
            days[3] = 30;
            days[4] = 31;
            days[5] = 30;
            days[6] = 31;
            days[7] = 31;
            days[8] = 30;
            days[9] = 31;
            days[10] = 30;
            days[11] = 31;
            return days[month];
        }

        function getMonthName(month) {
            var mn = new Array(12);
            mn[0] = "January";
            mn[1] = "February";
            mn[2] = "March";
            mn[3] = "April";
            mn[4] = "May";
            mn[5] = "June";
            mn[6] = "July";
            mn[7] = "August";
            mn[8] = "September";
            mn[9] = "October";
            mn[10] = "November";
            mn[11] = "December";
            return mn[month];
        }

        function monthName(month) {
            var mn = new Array(12);
            mn[0] = "Jan";
            mn[1] = "Feb";
            mn[2] = "Mar";
            mn[3] = "Apr";
            mn[4] = "May";
            mn[5] = "Jun";
            mn[6] = "Jul";
            mn[7] = "August";
            mn[8] = "September";
            mn[9] = "October";
            mn[10] = "November";
            mn[11] = "December";
            return mn[month];
        }

        function setCal() {
            var firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
            var startDay = firstDay.getDay();
            firstDay = null;
            var days = getDays(month, year);
            drawCal(startDay + 1, days, date, monthName, year, month);
        }

        function previousMonth() {
        document.getElementById('cal').innerHTML = "";
            month--;
            var monthName = getMonthName(month);
            var firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
            var startDay = firstDay.getDay();
            firstDay = null;
            var days = getDays(month, year);
            drawCal(startDay + 1, days, date, monthName, year, month);
            if (monthName === "January"){
                year--;
                month = 11;
                monthName = getMonthName(month);
                firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
                startDay = firstDay.getDay();
                firstDay = null;
                days = getDays(month, year);
            drawCal(startDay + 1, days, date, monthName, year, month);
            }
        }

        function nextMonth() {
        document.getElementById('cal').innerHTML = "";
            month++;
            var monthName = getMonthName(month);
            var firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
            var startDay = firstDay.getDay();
            firstDay = null;
            var days = getDays(month, year);
            drawCal(startDay + 1, days, date, monthName, year, month);
            if (monthName === "December"){
                year++;
                month = 0;
                monthName = getMonthName(month);
                firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
                startDay = firstDay.getDay();
                firstDay = null;
                days = getDays(month, year);
            drawCal(startDay + 1, days, date, monthName, year, month);
            }
        }

        function drawCal(startDay, lastDate, date, monthName, year, month) {
            var headerHeight = 50;
            var border = 2;
            var cellspacing = 4;
            var headerSize = "+3";
            var colWidth = 60;
            var dayCellHeight = 25;
            var cellHeight = 40;
            var todayColor = "red";
            var text = "";
            text += '<div id="cal">';
            text += '<TABLE BORDER=' + border + ' CELLSPACING=' + cellspacing + '>';
            text += '<TH COLSPAN=7 HEIGHT=' + headerHeight + '>';
            text += '<FONT SIZE=' + headerSize + '>';
            text += monthName + ' ' + year;
            text += '</FONT>';
            text += '</TH>';

            var openCol = '<TD WIDTH=' + colWidth + ' HEIGHT=' + dayCellHeight + '>';
            var closeCol = '</TD>';

            var weekDay = new Array(7);
            weekDay[0] = "Sunday";
            weekDay[1] = "Monday";
            weekDay[2] = "Tuesday";
            weekDay[3] = "Wednesday";
            weekDay[4] = "Thursday";
            weekDay[5] = "Friday";
            weekDay[6] = "Saturday";

            text += '<TR ALIGN="center" VALIGN="center">';
            for (var dayNum = 0; dayNum < 7; ++dayNum) {
                text += openCol + weekDay[dayNum] + closeCol;
            }
            text += '</TR>';


            var digit = 1;
            var curCell = 1;

            for (var row = 1; row <= Math.ceil((lastDate + startDay - 1) / 7); ++row) {
                text += '<TR ALIGN="right" VALIGN="top">';
                for (var col = 1; col <= 7; ++col) {
                    if (digit > lastDate)
                        break;
                    if (curCell < startDay) {
                        text += '<TD></TD>';
                        curCell++;
                    } else {
                        if (digit == date) {
                            text += '<TD HEIGHT=' + cellHeight + '>';
                            text += '<FONT COLOR="' + todayColor + '">';
                            text += digit + "   ";
                            text += '</FONT>';
                            text += '</TD>';
                        } else
                            text += '<TD HEIGHT=' + cellHeight + '>' + digit + '</TD>';
                        digit++;
                    }
                }
                text += '</TR>';
            }


            text += '</TABLE>';
            text += '</CENTER>';
            text += '</div>';
            text += '<button onclick="previousMonth()"><</button>';
            text += '<button onclick="nextMonth()">></button>';

            document.write(text);

        }

    </script></head>
<body onload="setCal()">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be better if you can use a container element and set its content rather than to use document.write()

```
<html>
<head><script>

        var now = new Date();
        var year = now.getFullYear();
        var month = now.getMonth();
        var monthName = getMonthName(month);
        var time = now.toLocaleTimeString();
        var date = now.getDate();
        now = null;
        var calElem = document.getElementById("cal");

        function febDays(year) {
            if (year % 4 == 0) {
                return 29;
            } else {
                return 28;
            }
        }

        function getDays(month, year) {
            var days = new Array(12);
            days[0] = 31;
            days[1] = febDays(year);
            days[2] = 31;
            days[3] = 30;
            days[4] = 31;
            days[5] = 30;
            days[6] = 31;
            days[7] = 31;
            days[8] = 30;
            days[9] = 31;
            days[10] = 30;
            days[11] = 31;
            return days[month];
        }

        function getMonthName(month) {
            var mn = new Array(12);
            mn[0] = "January";
            mn[1] = "February";
            mn[2] = "March";
            mn[3] = "April";
            mn[4] = "May";
            mn[5] = "June";
            mn[6] = "July";
            mn[7] = "August";
            mn[8] = "September";
            mn[9] = "October";
            mn[10] = "November";
            mn[11] = "December";
            return mn[month];
        }

        function monthName(month) {
            var mn = new Array(12);
            mn[0] = "Jan";
            mn[1] = "Feb";
            mn[2] = "Mar";
            mn[3] = "Apr";
            mn[4] = "May";
            mn[5] = "Jun";
            mn[6] = "Jul";
            mn[7] = "August";
            mn[8] = "September";
            mn[9] = "October";
            mn[10] = "November";
            mn[11] = "December";
            return mn[month];
        }

        function setCal() {
            var firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
            var startDay = firstDay.getDay();
            firstDay = null;
            var days = getDays(month, year);
            drawCal(startDay + 1, days, date, monthName, year, month);
        }

        function previousMonth() {
        document.getElementById('cal').innerHTML = "";
            month--;
            var monthName = getMonthName(month);
            var firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
            var startDay = firstDay.getDay();
            firstDay = null;
            var days = getDays(month, year);
            drawCal(startDay + 1, days, date, monthName, year, month);
            if (monthName === "January"){
                year--;
                month = 11;
                monthName = getMonthName(month);
                firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
                startDay = firstDay.getDay();
                firstDay = null;
                days = getDays(month, year);
            drawCal(startDay + 1, days, date, monthName, year, month);
            }
        }

        function nextMonth() {
        document.getElementById('cal').innerHTML = "";
            month++;
            var monthName = getMonthName(month);
            var firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
            var startDay = firstDay.getDay();
            firstDay = null;
            var days = getDays(month, year);
            drawCal(startDay + 1, days, date, monthName, year, month);
            if (monthName === "December"){
                year++;
                month = 0;
                monthName = getMonthName(month);
                firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
                startDay = firstDay.getDay();
                firstDay = null;
                days = getDays(month, year);
            drawCal(startDay + 1, days, date, monthName, year, month);
            }
        }

        function drawCal(startDay, lastDate, date, monthName, year, month) {
            var headerHeight = 50;
            var border = 2;
            var cellspacing = 4;
            var headerSize = "+3";
            var colWidth = 60;
            var dayCellHeight = 25;
            var cellHeight = 40;
            var todayColor = "red";
            var text = "";
            text += '<div id="cal">';
            text += '<TABLE BORDER=' + border + ' CELLSPACING=' + cellspacing + '>';
            text += '<TH COLSPAN=7 HEIGHT=' + headerHeight + '>';
            text += '<FONT SIZE=' + headerSize + '>';
            text += monthName + ' ' + year;
            text += '</FONT>';
            text += '</TH>';

            var openCol = '<TD WIDTH=' + colWidth + ' HEIGHT=' + dayCellHeight + '>';
            var closeCol = '</TD>';

            var weekDay = new Array(7);
            weekDay[0] = "Sunday";
            weekDay[1] = "Monday";
            weekDay[2] = "Tuesday";
            weekDay[3] = "Wednesday";
            weekDay[4] = "Thursday";
            weekDay[5] = "Friday";
            weekDay[6] = "Saturday";

            text += '<TR ALIGN="center" VALIGN="center">';
            for (var dayNum = 0; dayNum < 7; ++dayNum) {
                text += openCol + weekDay[dayNum] + closeCol;
            }
            text += '</TR>';


            var digit = 1;
            var curCell = 1;

            for (var row = 1; row <= Math.ceil((lastDate + startDay - 1) / 7); ++row) {
                text += '<TR ALIGN="right" VALIGN="top">';
                for (var col = 1; col <= 7; ++col) {
                    if (digit > lastDate)
                        break;
                    if (curCell < startDay) {
                        text += '<TD></TD>';
                        curCell++;
                    } else {
                        if (digit == date) {
                            text += '<TD HEIGHT=' + cellHeight + '>';
                            text += '<FONT COLOR="' + todayColor + '">';
                            text += digit + "   ";
                            text += '</FONT>';
                            text += '</TD>';
                        } else
                            text += '<TD HEIGHT=' + cellHeight + '>' + digit + '</TD>';
                        digit++;
                    }
                }
                text += '</TR>';
            }


            text += '</TABLE>';
            text += '</CENTER>';
            text += '</div>';
            text += '<button onclick="previousMonth()"><</button>';
            text += '<button onclick="nextMonth()">></button>';

            document.getElementById('calc').innerHTML=text;

        }

    </script></head>
<body onload="setCal()">
    <div id="calc"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is it possible to add an event to a certain date?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to clear any HTML element you would just
***DO NOT*** use `document.write()` it clears the whole page.

It's the `document.write()` It always stays there no matter what. Try not to use document.write()

use `createElement('div')` instead. It's much more clean, you can keep track of the elements, and they're static, unless you want them to change. everything is under your control.

```
 document.getElementById('Clear_This_Div_id').innerHTML = '';
```

This will usually clear the element

Answer (score 0):

Without changing much of the other part of your code, you can just change the

```
document.write(text);
```

to

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = text;
```

This will clear off the previous content before putting the new one, since you are putting in the `body` every time.